# How to find number of columns in shell script?

Tags: unix, csv, awk

I am having text file say 01-01-2013.txt and it has contents as below

```
cat 01-01-2013.txt | cut -d',' -f1-10 | head -6
```

```
TIMESTAMP,DATE,HOUR_MINUTE,CAWFM,CSQ2,DBCRIS.CA.MSG,DBI.MSBR.INCOMING.Q,DBI.MSBR.INCOMING.Q.ERROR,DBT.CA.RECEIVE.CUST,DBT.CA.RECEIVE.CUST.ERROR
20130101000019,01.01.2013,00:00,0,0,0,0,0,6893,31
20130101000133,01.01.2013,00:01,0,0,0,0,0,6858,31
20130101000246,01.01.2013,00:02,0,0,0,0,0,6661,31
20130101000359,01.01.2013,00:03,0,0,0,0,0,6314,31
20130101000512,01.01.2013,00:05,0,0,0,0,0,6074,31
```

When i tried to find number of columns i have used below command and i m not getting the expected result as below. its just returning 1

```
awk 'BEGIN {IFS=","};END{print NF}' 01-01-2013.txt
```

Result

1

Please help me to find out the total number of columns.

Comment: is this a CSV that you want to know about columns on?  If not, how are you defining what a column is?  Also, what answer do you want if different rows have different column counts?

Answer (score 2):

Your example does not work because `awk` does not use the name `IFS`, the input field separator is called `FS` (but it does use `OFS` for the output field separator).

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=","}END{print NF}' csv
10
```

But you can go without reading the whole file, e.g. by reading only the first line

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==1{print NF;exit}' csv
10
```

or the first line that matches `/,/`

```
$ awk -F, '/,/{print NF;exit}' csv
10
```

If you only want to remove the first two columns, I don't understand why you don't stick with `cut` like in your question:

```
$ cut -d, -f3- csv
HOUR_MINUTE,CAWFM,CSQ2,DBCRIS.CA.MSG,DBI.MSBR.INCOMING.Q,DBI.MSBR.INCOMING.Q.ERROR,DBT.CA.RECEIVE.CUST,DBT.CA.RECEIVE.CUST.ERROR
00:00,0,0,0,0,0,6893,31
00:01,0,0,0,0,0,6858,31
00:02,0,0,0,0,0,6661,31
00:03,0,0,0,0,0,6314,31
00:05,0,0,0,0,0,6074,31
```

Comment: Did you try my examples? But as said, if you want to remove columns, don't use `awk` but use `cut` instead.

Comment: Adrian , Actually i m implementing some logic in my script ie after removing 2 columns i need to  find out sum of other columns and the need to remove the columns which has total 0 at last need to add total to respective columns

Comment: don't you just love questions like "I want to do X" and when you tell them how to do X they say "actually, I want to do Y". I wonder what goes through their minds....

Comment: @EdMorton Actually, it is worse. See the prior comment in Steven's answer. It's more like "I want to do X...no wait, I want to do Y. I mean Z ...".

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '{print NF}' FS=, 01-01-2013.txt
10
10
10
10
10
10
```

Comment: Hi Steven actually i need to remove first 2 columns and copy to new file

Answer (score 0):

To find the total no of columns :

**Input_file**

```
TIMESTAMP,DATE,HOUR_MINUTE,CAWFM,CSQ2,DBCRIS.CA.MSG,DBI.MSBR.INCOMING.Q,DBI.MSBR.INCOMING.Q.ERROR,DBT.CA.RECEIVE.CUST,DBT.CA.RECEIVE.CUST.ERROR
20130101000019,01.01.2013,00:00,0,0,0,0,0,6893,31
20130101000133,01.01.2013,00:01,0,0,0,0,0,6858,31
20130101000246,01.01.2013,00:02,0,0,0,0,0,6661,31
20130101000359,01.01.2013,00:03,0,0,0,0,0,6314,31
20130101000512,01.01.2013,00:05,0,0,0,0,0,6074,31
```

**Awk Code**

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=","} ; END{print NF}' Input_file
```

**Output**

```
10
```

**Perl Solution**

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @cols = split(',', $_);
my $n = @cols;
print "row $. =  $n columns\n";
```

Save the code as code.pl and execute as

```
$> perl -n code.pl Input_file
```

**Perl Output**

```
row 1 =  10 columns
row 2 =  10 columns
row 3 =  10 columns
row 4 =  10 columns
row 5 =  10 columns
row 6 =  10 columns
```